# Was Fudge ever punished for his criminal negligence?

Tags: harry-potter

Did JKR ever address what punishment, if any, Cornelius Fudge suffered for basically allowing Voldemort's second rise to power 100% unmolested, by putting the full weight of the Ministry against the Order of the Phoenix and Dumbledore (and telling the Wizarding world Voldemort didn't return) instead of working to stop the rise (not to mention assisting Voldemort in his plans by using Dementors in Azkaban; surrounding himself with Death Eaters in the Ministry, villifying Harry Potter and helping Umbridge)?

This seems at best, criminal negligence, and at worst, treason.

We know he was voted out of office when Voldemort finally announced his presence at the Ministry at the end of OotP, but that seems woefully inadequate given his actions and their deadly consequences.

NOTE: I read " [What happened to Cornelius Fudge after he resigned from his post of Minister for Magic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64238/what-happened-to-cornelius-fudge-after-he-resigned-from-his-post-of-minister-for)" but none of the answers there (nor the question) specifically address the punishment.

Comment: Near-criminal is another way of saying not-criminal.

Comment: @Richard - fixed

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64238/3567 My statement “I don’t know of any canon sources about this” still stands, and includes the fact that I don’t know about any punishment for his crimes.

Comment: I don't see how this isn't a dupe.

Comment: @Richard - I disagree, but feel free to vote

Comment: @alexwlchan's answer seems pretty comprehensive regarding all we know about Fudge's activities post-office.

Comment: Could you clarify _why_ that other question doesn't answer it? It tells us we don't know what happened, so we do not know about any punishment either. Should anything surface about a possible punishment, for instance through _Pottermore_, I find it hard to imagine an answer to the other question that doesn't include anything about that.

Comment: essentially the extent of his punishment was that he had to resign, its very hard to assign punishment to a leader, especially one that had the backing of the whole organization behind him. the allies had trouble with this in ww2, the top german generals were the only ones that were really "punished" and tried for war crimes, and the majority of peons were simply forgiven for just following order. Fudge didnt do anything illegal persay, he just acted poorly, he didn't knowingly sell out wizard kind. just ignored a problem. therefor no crime was committed, however he was found to be unfit.